# Building git from sources, missing getopt library on debian jessie

Tags: debian, git, packages, build

I'm following these instruction to build git from source:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

I get the error "Unable to find packge getopt", also after an apt update.
Cannot find a package containing the library on debian packages archive.

Any idea on how to solve it?

I'm running it into a docker container:

```
from debian:latest

RUN apt-get update

# git installation

RUN apt-get install \
  dh-autoreconf \
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
  libexpat1-dev \
  gettext  \
  libz-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  asciidoc \
  xmlto \
  docbook2x \
  getopt

RUN wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.13.0.tar.gz -P /tmp/src/git \
  tar -zxf /tmp/src/git/v2.13.0.tar.gz -C /tmp/bin/git \
  cd /tmp/bin/git \
  make configure \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr \
  make all doc info \
  make install install-doc install-html install-info
```

Comment: I did try those commands on a freshly install Debian Jessie, after the 6 packages being asked to install it works perfectly, do you get the unable during the configure step ?

Comment: I'm running it in a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use gnulib since there is not a getopt package.

Comment: Can you expand on *how* you resolved this?